# Strange behavior of jquery-ui.css googleapis vs localhost

Tags: jquery, html, css, local

If i include  jquery-ui.css from google server - it wors fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
```

http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/jVVrzv

[image]

but if i download it to localstorage it behaviors differently
position of divs became relative.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" >
```

[image]

And the same thing if i include it from other online service on localhost,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/oYYzbw.css" >,
```

but in online there will be no problems.

http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/ZBBppG

I assume this happens because of different loading speed, but would appreciate if someone explain this behaviour.

Comment: Can you check if your console shows any errors or warnings?

Comment: jquery.js:3 GET file:///E:/project/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use something like `file://` or `C:/`, that does not support cross origin requests.

You can install a webserver on your local PC or upload it somewhere else to support the cross origin requests